# Compare density of rationals to the density of integers

Tags: cardinals, rational-numbers

Is is possible to somehow quantitatively compare the density of rational numbers to the density of integer numbers, ascribing to the both a number characterizing the density?

Answer (score 1):

My intuition says that
since distinct integers
differ by at least one
and rationals are arbitrarily close,
the density of the integers
should be zero
and the density of the rationals
should be positive.

If you throw in the reals,
I'll throw in the towel.

Comment: No, I want a measure where the desnsity of integers is not zero. And greater than the density of, say, evens.

Comment: If the density of the integers is positive, I find it hard to see how the density of the rationals would not be infinite.

Comment: OK, infinite but quantify it. Use ordinals, cardinals, complex numbers, whatever else. But in such a way that the desities came different.

Comment: @Anixx Perhaps you should specify that you want both of the "densities" to be positive. For the reason Marty gives, probably any quantity for which the values assigned to $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Q$ are both positive doesn't deserve to be called a "density".

Comment: @Travis  Can we compare the density of rationals to the density of a uniform dense countable set at all? For instance the density of rationals to the density of its subset - rationals with, say, even numerator or denomenator?